# Storing text box values in temporary table

Tags: javascript, mysql, jsp

I have a form that contain ten text boxes for entering some data. That form has a submit button and a next button. When I click on the next button, it has to open again ten text boxes, and has to store previous information into a temporary table in a MySQL database or in any other way. And finally, if I click on the submit button, it has to store that complete information into another permanent MySQL database table.

How can I do this?

This is what I tried so far:

```
<form name="form2" action="addingstuden_data.jsp" method="POST">
    <table align="center">
        <th colspan="3" class="style30"><font size="5">Adding Students for<%=stream%>-<%=year3%></th>
    </table>

    <table align="center" border="1">
        <tr>
            <td class="heading" align="center" >SNo</td>
            <td class="heading" align="center" >Student Id</td>
            <td class="heading" align="center">Student Name</td>
        </tr>
        <% 
            int i;
            for(i=0;i<62;i++)
            {
        %>
        <tr>
            <td><input type="text" name="SNo" value="<%=i%>" id="r2" size="1"> </td>
            <td><input type="text" name="stdid"  id="sid" size="4" value=""> </td> 
            <td><input type="text" name="stdname"  id="sname" value=""> </td>
        </tr> 
        <% } %>
    </table>
    <table width="100%" class="pos_fixed">
        <tr>
            <td align="center" class="border"><input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit"> </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this, Style it according to your need

```
<form name="myform" method="POST" action="youraction">
<div id="forms">
 <input type="text" name="feilds[]">
 <input type="text" name="feilds[]">
<input type="text" name="feilds[]">
<input type="text" name="feilds[]">
<input type="text" name="feilds[]">
<input type="text" name="feilds[]">
<input type="text" name="feilds[]">
<input type="text" name="feilds[]">
<input type="text" name="feilds[]">
<input type="text" name="feilds[]">
</div>
<input type="button" name="next" value="next" onclick="next()">
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Javascript code

```
function next()
{
 var ele = document.getElementById('forms');

 for(var i=0;i<10;i++)
 {
    var name = document.createElement("input");
    name.setAttribute('type',"text");
    name.setAttribute('name',"feilds[]");
    ele.appendChild(name);
 }    

}
```

On server side loop through feilds[] array and get all the values